# if/else statement doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to programming and this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char name[50];
cout << "Please enter your name : " << endl;
cin >> name;

if (name[0] = 'M')
{
    cout << "Your initial name is M" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Your initial name is not M" << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

When I run my code, I typed "Mark" in the window and the program said "Your initial name is M".That works fine [image: image 1]
but when I type "John" in the window, the program still said "Your initial name is M" instead of "Your initial name is not M" [image: image 2]
and I am wondering why.Are there something missing in my code? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `name[0] = 'M'` should be `name[0] == 'M'`, obvious duplicate though.

Comment: Voting to close since the error is caused by typo.

Comment: And here we go with 4 answers to this question, seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (name[0] = 'M')
```

should have to be

```
if (name[0] == 'M')
```

`=` is used as an assignment operator. it will assign `M` to `name[0]`.
Use `==` to compare value.

`=` assign value from right hand side to left hand side.
`==` compare value of right hand side with left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

its '==' and not '=' in your if statement. '=' is for simple assignment operator and == is for comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

Change the assignment operator **=** in your if statement to an equal to operator **==**

```
if (name[0] == 'M')
{
    cout << "Your initial name is M" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Your initial name is not M" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (name[0] = 'M')
```

In C and C++, `=` is for assignment.